# Two button jquery program

Tags: jquery, html, button

I got two buttons on my html page each with a word. Of them, one button is hidden and one is visible at first. What I want to do is, if I click one button, the other one should hide and when i click the other one, the previous one should show up and the clicked one should hide. This process should go on for every click. Here is what I have tried:

```
$('#fcb_pt_t1-1').click(function(){ 
    $(this).hide(); 
    $('#fcb_pt_yt1').addClass('your_team'); 
    $('#fcb_pt_yt1').click(function(){     
        $(this).hide(); 
        $('#fcb_pt_t1-1').show(); 
    }); 
});
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: *'I want jquery program to do it'* But, what you have tried for it?

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: $('#fcb_pt_t1-1').click(function(){ 
 
   $(this).hide(); $('#fcb_pt_yt1').addClass('your_team');
  
     $('#fcb_pt_yt1').click(function(){
    $(this).hide(); $('#fcb_pt_t1-1').show();
    
 });
 });    This is the jquery i wrote, it just happens for one click, not for continuous clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested click handlers are a bad idea, as you will end up adding more handlers on each successive click. Try this instead:

```
$('#fcb_pt_t1-1').click(function(){ 
    $(this).hide(); 
    $('#fcb_pt_yt1').addClass('your_team').show();
});

$('#fcb_pt_yt1').click(function(){     
    $(this).hide(); 
    $('#fcb_pt_t1-1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$(function(){
 $('#a').on('click',function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('#b').show();
});

$('#b').on('click',function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('#a').show();
});
});
```